# JQM: Adding click function to a button AFTER Page load via Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
    <a href="#" id="menubtn" class="ui-btn">Menu</a>

    <script>$(document).on("pageshow", menu);</script>
</div>
```

js:

```
function menu() {
    $('#menubtn').on('click', function () {
        ...
    });

    alert("menu");
}
```

does only work with the first pageload, 
after clicking a link JQM loads the link via ajax...
menu() is called, alert viewable... but no click event added to the link

any ideas?

Comment: Use `pagecreate` instead of `pageshow`. Also note that `pageshow` is deprecated and will be removed in 1.5 release.

Comment: Change $('#menubtn').on('click', function () {... to $(document).on('click', '#menubtn',  function () {

Comment: thanks... but makes no difference